# ¿Como Copiar Datos de una columna a otro ? Al mismo tiempo insertar datos creados por mi

Tags: mysql

Mi pregunta es como puedo copiar datos de una tabla a otra y al mismo tiempo insertar datos por mi nuevos.
Es decir, necesito meter datos de un nuevo trabjador, pero quiero que ese trabjador tenga algunos datos igual que otro trabajador , pero teniendo en cuenta logicamente el tendrá su nombre y apellido disntino a al otro.
Quierp hacerlo en una misma sentencia.

------>>>> Añadir a la oficina de Londres otro empleado, Luis Valverde, con número de empleado 436, con los mismos datos que el empleado Alberto Soria pero su jefe será el director de la oficina de Madrid.*/ Son unos ejercicios que estoy praticando porque tengo un examen el lunes :/

Gracias de antemano!!!!!

Comment: Revisa [ask]. Tu pregunta es demasiado abierta y nos podemos imaginar mil escenarios y mil formas de resolverlo... cuando preguntes trata de ser lo mas especifico posible. ¿Cual es la tabla origen?, ¿cual es la tabla destino?, ¿Cuales son sus esquemas?

Comment: /*12. Añadir a la oficina de Londres otro empleado, Luis Valverde, con número de empleado 436, 
con los mismos datos que el empleado Alberto Soria pero su jefe será el director de la oficina de Madrid.*/    Son unos ejercicios que estoy praticando porque tengo un examen el lunes :/

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que quieres insertar datos en la `tabla2` y la organizacion del nuevo registro es la misma que tiene el registro con id=1 de la tabla `tabla1`, puedes hacer algo como:

```
insert into tabla2 (organizacion, nombre, apellido) values ((select organizacion from tabla1 where id=1), "nuevo nombre", "nuevo apellido")
```

Ese podría ser un ejemplo

Comment: No son los mismos registros. Tengo que meterlos algunos nuevos , tales como nombre ,CodigoEmpleado y apellidos

Comment: Si, en mi ejemplo tampoco son los mismos registros, es uno de referencia y uno nuevo con datos distintos... que es lo que buscas entonces?

Comment: Lo he intendado pero nome funciona......lo he intenado de esta forma

Comment: INSERT INTO Empleados (CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1,Apellido2,Extension,Email,CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto) values 
 (1,'LUIS', 'VALVERDE',null, 436,null, 'LONDON-UK',3, 'Subdirector Ventas') (Email) from Empleados where nombre like=" Alberto";

Comment: Pero eso que pones no tiene sentido... esa sentencia SQL con ese `(Email)` no va a correr nunca

Comment: y en tu ejemplo no usas lo que te sugiero :(

Comment: Pues esto:      insert into Empleados (CodigoEmpleado,Nombre,Apellido1) values ((select Email,Puesto from Empleados where nombre ="Alberto"), "LUIS", "VALVERDE");

Comment: Pero me sale este error ----->>>> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Exacto... para cada campo solo puedes consultar un campo... ahi estás consultando 2 campos para un campo... debes repetir el select para el primer campo y para el segundo campo. en CodigoEmpleado quieres insertar el resultado de (Email,Puesto) y eso no se puede